# "The earlier we leave, the earlier we'll arive"-type construction

Tags: grammar

Was not sure how to title my question because I don't know who to explain such grammar pattern.

I came across something like that in Tae Kim's guide:

> 勉強をすればするほど、頭がよくなるよ。 (The more you study, the more you will become smarter.)

But it seems it only applies to verbs, "the more you do something, the more something will happen".

I was wondering how to say something like "the earlier we leave, the earlier we'll arrive", "the faster you run, the faster you'll get tired" etc?

Those grammar patterns are similar in English but I have a feeling they're not that similar in Japanese and I have no idea how to find something like that.

Comment: Look at the other topic posted in @Flaw's comment.  But I'm confused about what you're asking.  You say the ～ば～ほど pattern only applies to verbs, but then you list two more examples that also have verbs.  Are you specifically looking for instances of using a pattern like this with nouns?  Or just confused on it in general?

Comment: @istrasci I guess what he or she is asking is whether it is possible to apply the ～ば～ほど pattern to adverbs to express "the earlier we leave, the earlier we'll arrive", "the faster you run, the faster you'll get tired", etc., and in the case it is not, what the appropriate expression should be.

Comment: @Noir We've had a question like that, too: [using 〜ば〜ほど with adverbs](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14332/using-%e3%81%b0-%e3%81%bb%e3%81%a9-with-adverbs)

Comment: @Earthliŋ Cool. Thanks for pointing that out :)